# Single bit of memory

Tags: integrated-circuit, memory

Is there an IC which provides 1 bit of memory?

I'm thinking something like an IC that has GND, VVC, input value, input set/clock, and output. It maintains its output value at HIGH or LOW until set/clock is pulled HIGH (or LOW), at which point input value is read and duplicated to output. If the supplied voltage drops below its operational range, it could either reset to LOW (volatile), or retain its value (non-volatile); either case is fine.

What would a part like this be called?

Is there a similar IC which has n input and n output, and is functionally n bits of memory? What would a part like this be called?

Comment: It's called "flop-flop" and "register" respectively.

Comment: [7474](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_7400_series_integrated_circuits)?

Comment: I've seen / built non volatile versions with tiny programmable potentiometers.

Comment: @SomeHardwareGuy seems to me that making a flip-flop out of a programmable potentiometer is kind of like when people make digital logic in minecraft.

Comment: True but it made for nice nv address lines back in the day.  Used to be a common fpga trick maybe there's better single bit nvram parts that don't require maintaining any code like a micro would.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That part is called a [flip flop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)).

You can get packages of one or several flip flops [here](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/integrated-circuits-ics/logic-flip-flops/2556318).

If n is much more than 8 or so, you will want a memory chip which offers some address and data bus.

Comment: Just knowing what they're called makes all the difference, so thanks! It looks like a [shift register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_register) would handle n bits with only 1 input instead of n inputs.

Comment: Yes but then you can only use them in a constrained way. This may be suitable for your situation but in a shift register the input of one bit is connected to the output of the previous bit.

Comment: Right. I was thinking of 7-segment displays, where shifting in each LED's value in quick succession, followed by 1 second or 1 minute of display time would work fine.